# Sub routine stops working after opening a file

Tags: excel, vba

After running the below line:

```
Workbooks.Open (strFilePath)
```

excel opens the file but the macro stops without any errors.

How do I get it continue so it runs   "......do something else "?

```
Sub openbook()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim strFilePath As String
        Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer, it As Variant
        Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

        Dim osho As Worksheet
        Dim lastrow As Integer
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim wb As Workbook

        Set osho = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

        fDialog.Title = "Select a file"

        If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
            strFilePath = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        End If


       Workbooks.Open (strFilePath)


       ......do something else


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the "do something else?" We need that detail to help.

Comment: What do you mean it stops? Put a break point `F9` after that line, run the code again and confirm that you won't be directed to the line after when the other workbook has been opened.

Comment: when i say it stopped I meant it exits subroutine.  I have a workbook with data in different worksheets.  I want the macro to copy records from each worksheet and paste it into a single worksheet in a different workbook. "strFilePath" variable is directory to where the workbook with data is saved.